# Prevent conversion of number to octal in js

Tags: javascript

I have below code

```
var oct = 017;

alert(oct);
```

If I used `parseInt(oct)` then its printing `17` but I need `017`.

Above code is alert 15 instead of 017. Please suggest how to get 017 instead of 15

Comment: Make it a string. Numbers don't get shown with leading zeroes. And use `parseInt( '017', 10 );` and `parseInt( '017', 8 );`, explicitly stating the radix if you  have to convert between them.

Comment: @Shilly That comment should be an answer :)

Comment: @Shilly's comment should be the answer - if visual representation is important, it should definitelly be a string -- NaN ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a string instead.  `var oct = "017"`  Or you could just remove the leading zero.  `var oct = 17`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard method [`Number.toString(radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) for converting a number to a string representing that number in a non-decimal number system:

```js
var oct = 017;

alert(oct.toString(8));
```